# Ansible variable with double backlash

Tags: ansible

I am in need to define a variable in Ansible to hold a Windows network share directory.

```
#From vars/main.yml

network_path: '\\x.org\b\c'

# from tasks/main.yml

name: Output network path value
debug:
  var: network_path
```

When I use this variable in the playbook, it's getting converted to below and the playbook fails.

```
\\\\x.org\\b\\c
```

As per yaml documentation, backlash character is included literally if enclosed in single quotes. However, it's not working with \

Can someone please let me know if I am making a mistake here and what is the correct way to define a variable here.

Regards,
Harish.

Comment: [edit] the question and post the code of [mre].

Comment: What you are currently showing is just a cosmetic issue since the debug output only escape the character in question. Within the variable it is still the vaule you have defined.

Answer (score 2):

The format depends on the [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html). For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    network_path: \\x.org\b\c

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: network_path
```

with the `default` callback shows (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook pb.yml

ok: [localhost] => {
    "network_path": "\\\\x.org\\b\\c"
}
```

There are no escapes in the `yaml` callback

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml

ok: [localhost] => 
  network_path: \\x.org\b\c
```

In both cases the debug

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: network_path|length
```

shows the length of the variable is 11.